# How to track completion and errors of multiple parallel shell commands?

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

How can I track the completion state and store errors (well, the entire log output) of multiple shell commands running in parallel?

I want to run 3 programs in parallel but I don't want to see their console logs while they are running. I want to instead display a list of all the programs and their exit status UPDATING IN REAL TIME.

```
# Script is started, no programs have completed
prog1 - Running...
prog2 - Running...
prog3 - Running...

# After some time passes, some programs will have completed
prog1 - Running...
prog2 - FAIL # exit code not 0
prog3 - PASS # exit code 0
```

Then, after all programs have finished running, I want to display the console logs of any failed program.

```
prog1 - FAIL
prog2 - FAIL 
prog3 - PASS
--- DONE ---
prog1 encountered an error. LOG:
# Then the entire prog1 log is printed. You would repeat this for every failed program
```

I know I can run programs in parallel with &

```
prog1 &
prog2 &
prog3
```

And I know I can send the stdout of a program to a temp file or something

```
prog1 > tempfile.txt
```

But I can't figure out how to track the process exit codes in realtime. I think I can do something with `wait` and then display only program logs that failed but I don't know how to store the completion status as a variable. I know `$?` gives you the exit code of the program that was LAST RUN but I want all of them, not just the last run. I need to be able to loop over all the result and then only print the temp logs of the failed programs. Any ideas?

Comment: In your case how do you define a failed programm? Why do you need to loop over all exit codes?

Comment: A failed program is any program with an exit code that is not 0. I want to collect all program exit codes and logs so that I can loop over all exit codes after every program has finished running to only display logs from failed (non 0) programs (successful program runs will also have logs but I don't want to output those)

Answer (score 1):

Without writing and testing all the code, I would do something like this:

Make a temporary directory where you will store the output log and the exit status of each program, something like:

```
tmpDir=$(mktemp -d ...)
```

Then start each program within a subshell, in the background, writing to a log file and saving the exit status, something like:

```
( prog1 > "$tmpDir/1.log" ; echo $? > "$tmpDir/1.es" ) &
```

Now go into a loop, waiting for all to finish. You can either test whether the exit status file exists, or use [pgrep](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-check-if-process-is-running-or-notonlinuxunix/) to know when complete.

When all are complete, exit the loop and `cat` the log for each process where the exit status is non-zero.